# How do I locate a table row based on the text of a cell in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

How do I locate a table row based on table cell data using the following HTML snippet:

```
<table id="BetaCustomersTable>
  <s:iterator>
    <tr>
      <td class="userTabletd">
        <s:property value="email" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay I found your HTML snippet - it was commented out. I also reworded your question, please let me know if I've misunderstood. Answer provided below.

Answer (score 2):

To locate a table row based on it containing a cell with specific text you can use the following XPath locator:

```
//tr[td[text()='myCellText']]
```